# 'Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component' while setting text on password field

Tags: uipath, uipath-activity

I have a bot to fillup the form on below URL

https://signup.gmx.com/#.1559516-header-signup1-1

For filling the password field, I am generating a string randomly and trying to fill it using 'Set Text' activity but it fails with below error

> Set Text 'INPUT  password': Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned
> from a call to a COM component.

I also tried using 'Type Into' activity with all Input Mode options like Hardware Events, Simulated etc. They don't give error but does not enter the password in to the text field.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your link does not work. Can you update with the proper URL please?

Comment: May be the Sign up link is dynamically generated. You can go to https://www.gmx.com/ and click Sign up link on the top to go to the form. Thanks in advance